# Set element attributes based on item properties in nativescript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-nativescript

Currently, I wonder if it is possible inside `ngFor` loop to call a function on an item element to set some properties. Otherwise, I would have to loop twice (first in the script part and second in the template part) and set just temporary properties to a model which should only have specific ones, but the code to set the property makes the template ungly and is redundant so I want to outsource it into a function.

For example:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items">
    <Label setProperties(el,item)></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

and

```
function setProperties(el,item) {
    el.text = item.fullname;
    let color = '';
    switch(item.state) {
        case 'success':
            let color = 'green';
            break;
        case 'fail':
            let color = 'red';
            break;
    }
    el.style.color = color;
}
```

Something like that, but of course in the flesh more complex ;-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Prefer to loop twice. Calling functions from view bindings is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: Okay, just out of interest can you briefly explain to me why this idea would be bad?

Comment: I know, but it's teleriks nativescript UI for building mobile apps.

Comment: Because methods in bindings would be called each time change detection runs and this can be very often. There just is no good way to accomplish what you want in the view.

Comment: Too bad. But thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be achieved either more or less by using `onItemLoading` event. To be honest, it acts quite similar as if you would loop over the items `onInit`, but the benefit is, that the `onItemLoading` event is a build-in way to achieve that aim.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/How-To/item-customization#the-itemloading-event

Answer (score 1):

This should be what youre after

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items">
    <Label [style.color]="item.state == 'success' ? 'green' : item.state == 'failed' ? 'red' : item.state == 'other' ? 'yellow' : 'blue' " [text]="item.fullname"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

--EDIT--

I added a multi switch as an example, you can make the multi as long as possible

Comment: Of course it is. In that simple case I would not ask for an answer. But the sample was just a sample and not the whole real project code :D Imagine there would be about ten cases in the switch or a deep nested property...

Comment: then write a multi switch statement?

Comment: You mean a nested ternary operator inside the attribute?

Comment: Possible, but not that nice.

Comment: use a function then?

Comment: Would be be better, but possible requires multiple functions. Seems to be the best achievable solution, I guess, because what I'm thinking of is not viable...

Comment: it only requires one function

Comment: In that example, that's true. But according  to my question there would be several properties to be set.

Comment: its still able to be done in just one function that returns a string

Comment: How would that differ from the example I proposed in the question above?

Comment: you would have `return ......;`'s and you would have the `[style.color]` property set to a function, not a variable

Comment: could you please post an example?